# How to retain the common columns from both the tables after merge() in R?

Tags: r, join, merge

I've been looking for a way to retain both the common columns in R merge, which usually drops one of the common columns from the data. Any help would be appreciated.

E.g.

A data.frame named `demographics` has ***"EmpID", "Sal", "Dob", "City"*** and `transaction` data.frame has ***"ID", "Loan1", "Bonus"***.

If do an inner join,

```
res <- merge(demographics, transaction, by.x = "EmpID", by.y = "ID")
```

The resultant table `res` will have the following columns

**"EmpID" "Sal" "Dob" "City" "Loan1" "Bonus"**

I want to include the "ID" column as well.

**"EmpID" "Sal" "Dob" "City" "ID" "Loan1" "Bonus"**

How it is possible in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably overkill (need to attach a package and there'll be an important performance overhead), but `fuzzyjoin` functions always keep both sides:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
fuzzy_inner_join(iris1,iris2,by=c(id = "IRISid"),`==`)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width id Petal.Length Petal.Width IRISid
# 1          5.1         3.5  1          1.4         0.2      1
# 2          4.9         3.0  2          1.4         0.2      2
# 3          4.7         3.2  3          1.3         0.2      3
```

**data**

```
iris1 <- data.frame(head(iris[1:2],3),id=1:3)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width id
# 1          5.1         3.5  1
# 2          4.9         3.0  2
# 3          4.7         3.2  3

iris2 <- data.frame(head(iris[3:4],3),IRISid=1:3)
#   Petal.Length Petal.Width IRISid
# 1          1.4         0.2      1
# 2          1.4         0.2      2
# 3          1.3         0.2      3
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to make use of the `sqldf` library, and just write out a query which preserves all columns:

```
library(sqldf)
sql <- "select d.*, t.* from demographics d inner join transaction t "
sql <- paste0(sql, "on d.EmpID = t.ID")

res <- sqldf(sql)
```

Comment: Ya, agreed `sqldf` can be an option but I wish to achieve it using the Base/dplyr/data.table syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think this extra column would be redundant, but you could just do `res$ID <- res$EmpID` after the merge to copy the column, right?